# !fullResponse?.response?.is_complete does not act as it supposed to do

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am having an issue to understand this:

```
!fullResponse?.response?.is_complete
```

I was thinking it is the same as

```
        fullResponse &&
      fullResponse.response &&
      'is_complete' in fullResponse.response &&
      !fullResponse.response.is_complete
```

but it is not and it breaks my code specially when is_complete does not present in fullResponse.response

Can anyone explain what this does : !fullResponse?.response?.is_complete and if there is a way to make it act as below?

```
            fullResponse &&
      fullResponse.response &&
      'is_complete' in fullResponse.response &&
      !fullResponse.response.is_complete
```

Comment: The negation operator is evaluated separately from the property chain. It's `!(fullResponse?.response?.is_complete)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part you've probably misunderstood is the precedence of these operators. Your code actually boils down to:

```js
!(
  //            vvvvvvv--- `== null`: either null or undefined
  (fullResponse == null) ? undefined
  :(fullResponse.response == null) ? undefined
  :fullResponse.response.is_complete
)
```

So, when either part of your lookup short-circuits with an `undefined`, it runs right into the negation and gets converted to `true`.

If you just want to return `false` in case of a short-circuit, then it's as easy as:

```js
//                                       vvvv--- this will turn into false
!(fullResponse?.response?.is_complete ?? true)
```

However, if you want `undefined` in this case, it's easier with a variable:

```js
const isComplete = fullResponse?.response?.is_complete
isComplete === undefined ? undefined : !isComplete
```

If you can't do that, you'll have to repeat the lookup:

```js
fullResponse?.response?.is_complete === undefined ? undefined : !fullResponse?.response?.is_complete
```

Comment: This might be one of the rare cases where `== false` is ok, if the OP is expecting a boolean result. Still confusing though, the extra variable and explicit comparison to `null` would definitely be preferable.